# Дефис после "авиа"

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис, сложные-слова

Авиа и железнодорожные билеты.
Нужен ли дефис после "авиа"?

По правилу: дефис применяется при записи конструкций с однородными членами, имеющими общий конечный элемент, если все члены, кроме последнего, представлены только начальными элементами.
А здесь "авиа" связано со словом "билеты", а не с конечным элементом "дорожные".

Мне кажется, дефис все-таки нужен, но не будет ли это противоречить правилу? Поменять на "железнодорожные и авиабилеты" возможности нет.

Comment: Keyti, в справочнике как раз есть аналогичные примеры: ***не двух-, а трёхэтажный дом; не только англо- и франко-, но и русскоязычные тексты***.

Comment: _Серж: в справочнике как раз есть аналогичные примеры: **не двух-, а трёхэтажный дом; не только англо- и франко-, но и русскоязычные тексты.**_ === Да совсем не аналогичны разбираемому все эти примеры!

Comment: Почему? В этих примерах последний элемент представлен отдельным словом, как в нашем примере. Ср.: ***англо- и русскоязычные тексты***.

Comment: Серж, здесь ведь англо- относится к "язычные", а не к слову тексты, поэтому пример не тот.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что дефис здесь нужен: **авиа- и железнодорожные билеты.**

Это краткая запись "авиабилеты и железнодорожные билеты", то есть два разных определения относятся к существительному "билеты", хотя выражены они различным образом.  Пример:[Авиа- и железнодорожные билеты](http://moskva.spravker3.ru/avia-i-zheleznodorozhnye-bilety/)

[Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.
СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ
М.: ЧеРо, 1999](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/30.htm)

1) При сочетании с помощью союза и двух или нескольких сложных существительных **с одинаковой второй частью** эта часть может приводиться только при последнем слове, а при предшествующих словах вместо нее пишется так называемый висячий дефис. Например: газо- и электросварка (ср. газосварка и электросварка);

2) Висячий дефис (см. §42, п. 13) употребляется и при сложных прилагательных, например: семнадцати- и восемнадцатилетние юноши и девушки; кукурузно-, картофеле-, льно-, хлопко- и силосоуборочные комбайны.

Answer (score 3):

***Авиа- и железнодорожные билеты.***

Keyti:

> Мне кажется, дефис все-таки нужен, но не будет ли это противоречить
>   правилу?

**Не будет.** В [**ПАС**](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=59#pp59) правило звучит так:

> **§ 112.** Дефис применяется при записи конструкций с однородными членами, имеющими общий конечный элемент, если все члены, кроме
>   последнего, представлены только начальными элементами; такой дефис
>   называют «висячим».

В нашем случае однородные члены: *авиа**билеты**, железнодорожные **билеты***. Общий конечный элемент в них —  ***билеты***. Первый однородный член представлен начальным элементом ***авиа-***.

См. также ответ на аналогичный вопрос (***"как правильно, «авиа- и морские перевозки» или «авиа и морские перевозки»?"***) справочной службы [**Грамоты.ру.**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=282947)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Только справка как раз и не давала ответа на вопрос про "авиа- и морские перевозки", там говорится о том, что "висячий дефис не зависит от слитного или дефисного написания сложных слов", а аналогичные примеры отсутствуют.

Comment: К сожалению, да: аналогичные примеры в ПАС не приведены. Но сама формулировка правила, представленная в этом справочнике, позволяет распространить это правило и на рассматриваемый нами случай... В отличие от  формулировки правила, имеющейся у Розенталя.

Comment: @Серж, Ваша корректировка моего ответа привела к появлению в нём пунктуационной ошибки. Что будем делать?

Comment: @ slava1947,могу откатить правку, могу исправить ошибку, если укажите какую. Я ваш текст не трогал. Только ссылку исправил.