# Как правильно написать свето- и ароматерапия?

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис, сложные-слова

Как правильно написать свето- и ароматерапия?
Нужен ли дефис после слова "свето?" ТерапиЯ или терапиИ (т.к. терапия не одна, а их две: свето- и арома-)?

Comment: Подобный вопрос недавно был: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433218/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/433221#433221. И еще один: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432606/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0.

Answer (score 1):

Написано правильно: **свето- и ароматерапия**

Не повторяя сказанного ранее о конструкциях с "висячим" дефисом (["Тепло и звукоизоляция" или "тепло- и звукоизоляция"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433218/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/433221#433221)), хочу ответить на вопрос, в каком числе ставить "терапия". "Терапия" в данном случае не самостоятельное слово, а вторая часть слова, общая для обоих однородных членов. Если перейти к "полной" записи, то из конструкции "свето- и ароматерапиЯ" получится "светотерапиЯ и ароматерапиЯ", а из конструкции "свето- и ароматерапиИ" получится "светотерапиИ и ароматерапиИ". Это дает ответ на вопрос о множественном числе.